# HA-Cluster / corosync / pacemaker: Active-Active cluster with service ip / service ip is not switching

Tags: pacemaker, high-availability, corosync

How to configure crm to migrate the ServiceIP if one Service is failed?

```
node 1: web01a \
    attributes standby=off
node 2: web01b \
    attributes standby=off
primitive Apache2 systemd:apache2 \
    operations $id=Apache2-operations \
    op start interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op monitor interval=15 timeout=100 start-delay=15 \
    meta
primitive PHP-FPM systemd:php7.4-fpm \
    operations $id=PHP-FPM-operations \
    op start interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op monitor interval=15 timeout=100 start-delay=15 \
    meta
primitive Redis systemd:redis-server \
    operations $id=Redis-operations \
    op start interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op monitor interval=15 timeout=100 start-delay=15 \
    meta
primitive ServiceIP IPaddr2 \
    params ip=1.2.3.4 \
    operations $id=ServiceIP-operations \
    op monitor interval=10 timeout=20 start-delay=0 \
    op_params migration-threshold=1 \
    meta
primitive lsyncd systemd:lsyncd \
    op start interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=100 \
    op monitor interval=15 timeout=100 start-delay=15 \
    meta target-role=Started
group ActiveNode ServiceIP lsyncd
group WebServer Apache2 PHP-FPM Redis
clone cl_WS WebServer \
    meta clone-max=2 notify=true interleave=true
colocation col_cl_WS_ActiveNode 100: cl_WS ActiveNode
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    have-watchdog=false \
    dc-version=2.0.3-4b1f869f0f \
    cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
    cluster-name=debian \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore \
    startup-fencing=false \
    maintenance-mode=false \
    last-lrm-refresh=1622628525 \
    start-failure-is-fatal=true
```

These services should always be started

- Apache2
- PHP-FPM
- Redis

If one of these services is not running, the node is unhelthy.
The **ServiceIP** and **lsyncd** should switch to an healthy node.

When I killed the apache2 process, the IP is not switched.

Comment: It seems to me that you've defined two separate groups but want the "ActiveNode" group to react to failures in the "WebServer" group. Why don't you define one group with all of the services? Or are you looking for a way to tie the groups together with a dependency?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I defined two groups, because the services in group `WebServer` should run always on both nodes (active-active). Only the services in  `ActiveNode` should run as active-passive

Comment: Given that Apache2 (in Webserver) runs on both nodes,  what do you want to happen if Apache2 is killed on the *inactive* node?

Comment: @JeffSchaller it should try to restart the process and mark the node as unhealthy.
The Service ip should never run on a unhealthy node